# Feeds not retrieving questions in chatroom

Tags: support, chat, rss

I'm one of the owners of [this chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11391/sql).

I want to set up some questions feed on the chatroom by adding a feed.

[image]

Yet, nothing is being retrieved by that feed e.g no questions are appearing neither as chat message nor with the slide-down ticker.

Why? Is it an issue with Stack Overflow or did I do something wrong?

PS: This is the kind of feed I'm trying to set:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql

I tried this too, but it does not help ...

> https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=sql&sort=newest

Comment: have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Hi @War yes and still not working ...

Comment: hmmm tried it myself ... same problem ... doesn't seem to be posting to my room either, same feed :(

Comment: @War do you want to be a mod on the sql room? Never asked you the question but I've been thinking a bit about it for a few days now...

Comment: Same here, the messages doesn't show up in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45753/paranormal) (for good few months), despite it's configured correctly and [RSS Feed URL](https://www.reddit.com/r/Paranormal/.rss) has some [new items](http://www.feedbucket.com/?src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.reddit.com%2Fr%2FParanormal%2F.rss). Same problem for _Message_ and _Ticker feeds_. Only [Stack Exchange feeds](http://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds/proposal/107299) are working fine. Sometimes some feeds are displayed in a slide-down ticker, but not often, as _Message_ aren't appearing at all.

Comment: As for workaround, re-adding (removing and adding again) all feeds items seems to work, not clear for how long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the page says:

> **RSS** or **ATOM** feedscan be used <...>

The link you mention in your question, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql`, isn't an RSS feed.

Luckily, there's a way to get an RSS feed for a tag. Look for this link at the bottom of the tag's page:

> [image]

This should be the resulting link:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=sql&sort=newest
```

Now, if you take a look at the xml returned from that feed, you'll see:

```
<updated>2016-09-27T10:09:56Z</updated>
```

XML feeds aren't "live". They update on a set interval.

Comment: Hi @cerbrus, that's what we did too and nothing is appearing ...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=sql&sort=newest

Comment: The _"Feed you're trying to set"_ in your question isn't an RSS feed.

Comment: you mean that one? http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=sql&sort=newest @cerbrus

Comment: @AndyK, look at the last link in your question.

Comment: I've updated my question @cerbrus

Comment: no update so far...

Comment: Hi @cerbrus, fees is being retrieved now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it works with rss feeds not links to pages so maybe try starting from here ...

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/

...

I stand corrected, further testing shows that it works with the feeds functionality too ... we were simply impatient in figuring it out :)